# cannot create a memfd error with Ubuntu 20.04 on windows10 wsl1

Tags: wsl, windows

follow the tutorial https://docs.substrate.io/tutorials/get-started/simulate-network/ ,when  i running the following command:

```bash
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/alice \
--chain local \
--alice \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9945 \
--rpc-port 9933 \
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator
```

I got `RuntimeApiError` error:

```
2022-06-25 18:59:19 Substrate Node    
2022-06-25 18:59:19 ✌️  version 4.0.0-dev-681a9d8e3e8    
2022-06-25 18:59:19 ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2022    
2022-06-25 18:59:19  Chain specification: Local Testnet    
2022-06-25 18:59:19   Node name: Alice    
2022-06-25 18:59:19  Role: AUTHORITY    
2022-06-25 18:59:19  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/alice/chains/local_testnet/db/full    
2022-06-25 18:59:19 ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)    
2022-06-25 18:59:31  Initializing Genesis block/state (state: 0xea25…5836, header-hash: 0xa711…99ac)    
2022-06-25 18:59:31  Loading GRANDPA authority set from genesis on what appears to be first startup.    
2022-06-25 18:59:32 Essential task `txpool-background` failed. Shutting down service.    
Error: Service(Client(RuntimeApiError(Application(Execution(RuntimeConstruction(Other("failed to instantiate a new WASM module instance: Insufficient resources: cannot create a memfd")))))))
```

my development environment:

`rustup show`

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/little/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
rustc 1.61.0 (fe5b13d68 2022-05-18)
```

`rustup +nightly show`

```
Default host: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu
rustup home:  /home/little/.rustup

installed toolchains
--------------------

stable-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (default)
nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

installed targets for active toolchain
--------------------------------------

wasm32-unknown-unknown
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu

active toolchain
----------------

nightly-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (overridden by +toolchain on the command line)
rustc 1.63.0-nightly (43347397f 2022-06-23)
```

Ubuntu Memory

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          16259        7315        8720          17         223        8813
Swap:         25514          54       25459
```

Comment: Can you add a bit more info on your machine specs? e.g. what's your CPU, how many gigs memory you have, is it a virtual machine, laptop? Thanks!

Comment: i use laptop but this project is work on win10 wsl  for ubuntu 20.04 subsystem;  cpu:Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-7700HQ CPU @ 2.80GHz   2.80 GHz ，machine arm:16.0 GB and operate system version is  21H2

Comment: Are you running WSL 2? What is the output of this: `wsl -l -v`? Most likely this is a WSL issue.

Comment: thanks,when i update wsl to wsl2 it's work well

Answer (score 2):

you can upgrade wslv2 in https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-on-wsl-2-is-generally-available , i was success! good luck !