# Error: failed to instantiate a new WASM module instance: Insufficient resources: cannot create a memf"

Tags: substrate-node-template, wasm, error

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on windows 10 wsl and when I run the command in my terminals:

```
./target/release/node-template \
--base-path /tmp/alice \
--chain local \
--alice \
--port 30333 \
--ws-port 9945 \
--rpc-port 9933 \
--node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 \
--telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
--validator
```

Getting error like this:

```
 ./target/release/node-template \
> --base-path /tmp/alice \
> --chain local \
> --alice \
> --port 30333 \
> --ws-port 9945 \ 
> --rpc-port 9933 \
> --node-key 0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001 \
> --telemetry-url "wss://telemetry.polkadot.io/submit/ 0" \
> --validator
2022-07-10 12:05:30 Substrate Node    
2022-07-10 12:05:30 ✌️  version 4.0.0-dev-9c89be106cb
2022-07-10 12:05:30 ❤️  by Substrate DevHub <https://github.com/substrate-developer-hub>, 2017-2022    
2022-07-10 12:05:30  Chain specification: Local Testnet
2022-07-10 12:05:30   Node name: Alice
2022-07-10 12:05:30  Role: AUTHORITY
2022-07-10 12:05:30  Database: RocksDb at /tmp/alice/chains/local_testnet/db/full
2022-07-10 12:05:30 ⛓  Native runtime: node-template-100 (node-template-1.tx1.au1)
Error: Service(Client(RuntimeApiError(Application(Execution(RuntimeConstruction(Other("failed to instantiate a new WASM module instance: Insufficient resources: cannot create a memfd")))))))
```

help me to find out the solutions

Comment: May be helpful: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/3445/cannot-create-a-memfd-error-with-ubuntu-20-04-on-windows10-wsl1

Answer (score 2):

This is probably not Substrate/Polkadot related, rather your execution operation system is for some reason blocking this particular system call. Try executing `memfd_create` from `C` or some other language to see if it the problem persists or not.

Related links:

- https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/memfd_create.2.html
- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56615488/getting-gcc-error-sys-memfd-h-no-such-file-or-directory

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
wsl --set-version Ubuntu 2
```

If you doubt you are on the right version, use:

```
wsl -l -v
```